# Format number in string with db2, error "the number of arguments specified for varchar is invalid"

Tags: java, database, string, db2, format

From my db2 I have to take a number, example:

```
1234.56
234
11:55
12323.88
```

and format in string:

```
1,234,56
234
11,55
12323.88
```

I tried:

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(VALUE(CASE WHEN X_Type='1' THEN Y_Type ELSE Y_Type*-1 END,0), '9G999D99', 'de_DE') as money
```

but

```
"the number of arguments specified for varchar is invalid"
```

How can I do it? another?

Comment: For Db2-server running on Linux/Unix/Windows, the varchar_format with 3 arguments requires the first argument to be a date or timestamp expression (yours appears to be a decfloat).  Also please edit your question to specify the Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i/series(as/400), or Linux/Unix/Windows) along with the Db2-server __version__   (essential when asking for help)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to code, but maybe this example will help

```
SELECT
    VARCHAR_FORMAT(col, CASE WHEN X_Type='1' THEN Y_Type ELSE Y_Type || 'MI'  END, 'de_DE') as money
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES 
       ('1','999G999D99', -4324)
    ,  ('2','999G999D99', -4324)
    ) AS T(X_Type,Y_Type, col)
```

which returns

```
MONEY      
-----------
  -4.324,00
  4.324,00-
```